# How to use cut command along with text qualifier

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, unix, ksh

I have a text files that contains comma separated values.
Example file formats:

```
cat abc.txt
A,B,C,D

cat xyz.txt
A,"1,2,3",C,D
```

I want to cut the second column from these files delimited by comma.

When I use cut command I get following output:

```
cut -d',' -f2 abc.txt
B
```

This is correct and expected output

```
cut -d',' -f2 xyz.txt
"1
```

This is not correct. The expected output is `"1,2,3"` or `1,2,3`

Is there a way we can cut the second column from xyz.txt using "" as the text qualifier. So that commas within "" will be skipped?

Comment: The `cut` command doesn't support non-trivial CSV format where fields can embed commas. You need to use a different tool, for example Python would be a good candidate. Also, in the context of your question it doesn't make sense to include [tag:bash] together with [tag:ksh] together with [tag:powershell]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `FPAT` functionality of `gawk`, try following. Since you are using `cut` I am assuming you could use `awk` also.

```
awk -v FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" '{print $2}'  Input_file
```

Adding information `FPAT` out of the box variable from `man awk` as follows:

> FPAT: A  regular  expression  describing the contents of the fields in
>   a record.  When set, gawk parses the input into fields, where the
>   fields match the regular expression, instead of using the value of the
>   FS variable as the field separator.

NOTE: As per @Walter A's warning in comments beware of 1st empty field here with this solution.

Comment: @P S, Could you please check my solution once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: With an empty fort field, you get field 3. Try `echo ',"1,2,3",C,D'`.

Comment: @WalterA, Honestly I had written and tested it with current samples only, didn't assume this condition. If possible you could remove down vote request you to remove it since code works for given samples. I will try to edit this solution then.

Comment: I tried to remove the downvote, but I can't. I get the message that my downvote is locked unless your answer is edited.

Comment: I removed the downvote, but you can add a warning about an empty first field.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PowerShell and the following command to achieve that:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\abc.txt -Header H1, H2, H3, H4 |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty H2
```

The `Import-Csv` command will import your file as CSV and adds some random headers (`-Header H1, H2, H3, H4`) because the file does not have any. After that it will select and expand the second column (`Select-Object -ExpandProperty H2`).

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed 4.4 this works

```
sed -r 's/(("[^"]*")|([^,]*)),(("[^"]*")|([^,]*)).*/\4/' xyz.txt
```

Explanation:
`Option -r`: Avoid needing backslashes
`("[^"]*",)`: A string in double quotes (also support first field in quotes like `"A,a,a",B,C,D`).
`([^,]*)`: When no quoted field is found, match until next comma.
`(("[^"]*")|([^,]*))`: Match one field in one of the above formats.
`,`: Just an `,` between the first and second field.
`(("[^"]*")|([^,]*)),(("[^"]*")|([^,]*))`: (First field) comma (second field)
`.*`: match remaining part of line (replace by nothing)
`\4`: The 4th remembered match